# If L1 is decidable and if L2 is included in L1, is L2 also decidable?

Tags: computer-science, inclusion-exclusion, turing-machines, decidability

Is this statement true or false and why ?

If $L_{1}$ is decidable and if $L_{2}$$\subseteq$$L_{1}$ then $L_{2}$ is also decidable.

I would be tempted to say yes, but i am really not sure. I am also not sure of the reasoning behind.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is the alphabet, is every subset of $\Sigma^*$ decidable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $L_2$ be *any* language.

Notice $L_2 \subseteq \Sigma^*$ (the language of *all* words) which is decidable!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Is my reasoning correct : The answer is true, since L2 is a subset of L1, it means that L2 can generate all strings generated by L1 so it has to be decidable. Is that a valid explanation ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No. What happens if $L_2$ is undecidable? Remember, EVERY language, even the undecidable ones, is a subset of $\Sigma^*$

Comment: @codetime Your comment contains three errors. (1) Languages don't generate strings; they contain strings. (2) L1 contains all the strings contained in L2, not vice-versa. (3) Even if it had been vice-versa, that has nothing to do with decidability.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Oh so the answer is false, since L2 contains all the strings of L1 but it doesn't mean that the language is decidable ? Does this make more sens ? Also, i don't really realize what the hint says. It seems to be a contradiction to my reflexion above haha. ( sorry if i'm a bit slow on this, haven't used subets in a while  and decidability is new to me) Thanks.